# cannot create plugin for PaymentInformationManagement

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, payment, quote, plugin

I'm trying to create plugin for **Magento/Checkout/Model/PaymentInformationManagement** class

When I'm placing the order, the program stops after constructor in my plugin class.

Here is **/etc/di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
<type name="Magento\Checkout\Model\PaymentInformationManagement">
    <plugin name="save-quote" type="Company\Newsletter\Model\Plugin\Checkout\MyPaymentInformationManagement" sortOrder="110"/>
</type>
</config>
```

And
**/Model/Plugin/Checkout/MyPaymentInformationManagement.php**

```
<?php

namespace Company\Newsletter\Model\Plugin\Checkout;

use Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteRepository;
use Magento\Checkout\Model\PaymentInformationManagement as 
PaymentManagement;
use Magento\Checkout\Api\Data\PaymentDetailsInterface;

class MyPaymentInformationManagement
{

/**
 * @var \Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteRepository
 */
protected $_quoteRepository;

/**
 * @param QuoteRepository $quoteRepository
 */
public function __construct(QuoteRepository $quoteRepository)
{
    $this->_quoteRepository = $quoteRepository;
}

public function beforeSavePaymentInformation(PaymentManagement $subject, $cartId, PaymentDetailsInterface $paymentInformation)
{
    //some code
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem lay in declaration of usage `Magento\Checkout\Api\Data\PaymentDetailsInterface`

and **PaymentDetailsInterface** $paymentInformation in method that is not Instance / missing Api connection.